# Extract particular string using Shell Script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

My text file contains data in the below format

```
{ "_id" : "abc" }
{ "_id" : "def" }
{ "_id" : "ghi" }
{ "_id" : "jkl" }
```

How can I extract the values from the above input and print it as below using shell commands

```
abc
def
ghi
jkl
```

Answer (score 0):

With a proper [json](/questions/tagged/json) parser:

```
jq '._id' file.json
```